# Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store

Tags: .net, vsto, clickonce

I signed the assembly with my VSTO 4.0 word add-in with strong name key file `.snk` and tried to uncheck Sign the ClickOnce manifest but after rebuild it appears again. After I tried to delete lines for ClickOnce manifest in `.csproj`, `.pfx` manifest appears after every rebuild.

Does anyone know solution to permanently delete temporary ClickOnce manifest?

Comment: See this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517440/why-am-i-getting-unable-to-find-manifest-signing-certificate-in-the-certificate

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The problem for me was that the checkbox "Signing the ClickOnce manifest" was checked. If you are not using signing uncheck it in 
Project Properties->signing->sign the clickonce manifests

Comment: Thanks! How in the world did this get checked?

Comment: And as for my case, first I had to check the "sign the clickonce manifests" option and generate a test cerificate. Than I signed an assembly with that test cert., uncheck that option again and only than signed with my real certificate. It seems, it had been looking for those manifests.

Comment: I had to uncheck both `Sign the ClickOnce manifests` and `Sign the assembly` check boxes under signing tab in project properties to get rid of the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Unchecking the "Signing the ClientOnce Manifest" doesn't always work. The solution is to remove the following lines from your csproj files

> <PropertyGroup>
>   <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>4FCE3F0998F4B89946A9D0346838E77A0C5C5568</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
>   </PropertyGroup>
>   <PropertyGroup>
>   <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
>   </PropertyGroup>
>   <PropertyGroup>
>   <SignManifests>false</SignManifests>
>   </PropertyGroup>