# Jenkins error MSB3323: Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, certificate

I am getting this error in Jenkins described in this post:[Why am I getting "Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store" in my Excel Addin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517440/why-am-i-getting-unable-to-find-manifest-signing-certificate-in-the-certificate)

However, this post:

1. Didn't mention about Jenkins.
2. I don't have enough reputation to
       comment.

So I am creating this one to ask.

The project was originally created in VS 10.0, but now we are trying to build it on our Jenkins server using MSTest 11.0. The error is:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2455,5): error MSB3323: Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store. [D:\Jenkins\jobs\OTPP.Proswap.VSTO.DeltaHedgeSwapAddIn.Development\workspace\DeltaHedgeSwapAddIn\DeltaHedgeSwapAddIn.csproj]
```

Then following the above post and this one:

http://manfredlange.blogspot.ca/2008/03/visual-studio-unable-to-find-manifest.html   ,

We removed all entries in `.csproj file`. Now has this error in Jenkins:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(156,9): error : Cannot build because the ClickOnce manifest signing option is not selected. To select this option, open the project property pages, click the Signing tab, and then select "Sign the ClickOnce manifests."
```

How would one proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instruction here to delete did resolve the issue: http://manfredlange.blogspot.ca/2008/03/visual-studio-unable-to-find-manifest.html

The user didn't push his delete to GitHub therefore the project file wasn't changed.