# Xamarin MSBuild - error MSB3323: Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store

Tags: ios, xamarin, msbuild

Whilst building my iOS app on Azure Mobile Center, I was getting this error:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3048,5): error MSB3323: Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store. [/Users/ci/agent/vstsagent/_work/1/s/Mobile/Mobile.iOS/Mobile.iOS.csproj]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517440/why-am-i-getting-unable-to-find-manifest-signing-certificate-in-the-certificate) I had to open up the iOS project and delete the following tags:

`<manifestcertificatethumbprint>...</manifestcertificatethumbprint>
<manifestkeyfile>...</manifestkeyfile>
<generatemanifests>...</generatemanifests>
<signmanifests>...</signmanifests>`